# Import Polymer 3 component into Angular 5 project

Tags: angular5, web-component, polymer-3.x

I'm starting with polymer 3 and i'm working on this tutorial https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/first-element/step-5, so basically i have the component js file as follows

**icon-toggle.js**

```js
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js';

class IconToggle extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        /* shadow DOM styles go here */
        :host {
          display: inline-block;
          --icon-toggle-color: lightgrey;
          --icon-toggle-outline-color: black;
          --icon-toggle-pressed-color: red;
        }
        iron-icon {
          fill: var(--icon-toggle-color, rgba(0,0,0,0));
          stroke: var(--icon-toggle-outline-color, currentcolor);
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        :host([pressed]) iron-icon {
          fill: var(--icon-toggle-pressed-color, currentcolor);
        }
      </style>
  
      <!-- shadow DOM goes here -->
      <iron-icon icon="[[toggleIcon]]"></iron-icon>

    `;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      pressed: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false,
        notify: true,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      },
      toggleIcon: {
        type: String
      }
    };
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));
  }
  toggle() {
    this.pressed = !this.pressed;
  }
}

customElements.define('icon-toggle', IconToggle);
```

Now I'm wondering how to import this and use it in an angular 5 app.

Comment: Import it as a module in the `index.html` and place the tag anywhere in your page. If you want to place it inside any component then take a look into `entryComponents:[]` of ngmodule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a new Angular app.

```
ng new with-polymer
```

From within `with-polymer` create a directory to store the web components in.

```
mkdir src/app/components
```

Copy your polymer component code to `src/app/components/icon-toggle.js`

Install the polymer dependencies.

```
npm install @polymer/iron-icon @polymer/polymer
```

Update `src/app/app.module.ts` to import `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and tell NgModule that custom elements will be in use.

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  ...
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Import `icon-toggle` in `src/app/app.module.ts`.

```
import './components/icon-toggle';
```

Add an `icon-toggle` to `src/app/app.component.html`.

```
<icon-toggle toggle-icon="star"></icon-toggle>
```

Start up the dev server.

```
npm start
```

Note that you will probably want to include some [web component polyfills](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs).